# Compare 2 two strings and complement the terms in R

Tags: r, regex, string, text, compare

So I've been trying to find a way to deal with this problem. I have 2 strings. For example:

> Drinkable Yoghurt Is Good for your health

and

> Drink Yog is good if you do not exceed

So what I want is tho complement the incomplete words and include the words that are not in both strings. THE ORDER OF THE TERMS IS NOT IMPORTANT NOR THE CASES.  So my result could be:

> Drinkable Yoghurt Is Good for your health if do not exceed

I just want to complement the strings. Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: Please see [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Neverminding case, these Drink`able` `Yog`hurt . But this `you`r  breaks the mold because the output includes `your` and `you`

Comment: @slnmissed that. I edited the example. Thank you . Cases don't Mather neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foo <- "Drinkable Yoghurt Is Good for your health"
bar <- "Drink Yog is good if you do not exceed"

foo_vec <- unlist(strsplit(foo, " "))
bar_vec <- unlist(strsplit(bar, " "))
```

Find the words in `foo` that are not contained inside words in `bar`, and vice versa, ignoring case.

```
foo_vec2 <- foo_vec[!apply(sapply(foo_vec, function(x) grepl(x, bar_vec, ignore.case = TRUE)), 2, any)]
bar_vec2 <- bar_vec[!apply(sapply(bar_vec, function(x) grepl(x, foo_vec, ignore.case = TRUE)), 2, any)]
```

Find the words in both, ignoring case.

```
both <- intersect(tolower(foo_vec), tolower(bar_vec))
```

Put everything together.

```
paste(c(both, foo_vec2, bar_vec2), collapse=" ")
#> [1] "is good Drinkable Yoghurt for your health if do not exceed"
```

Comment: That's great! worked like wonder. Thanks a lot!. I'm not really good at mixing regex and apply. Thank you. Just one question, what happened to the Yog and Drink??? O.o

Comment: I drank the Yog, because it's good for my health if I do not exceed. Ha ha, actually, run the `sapply(.......)` code from what I wrote. Then run `apply(sapply(.......))`. Then put a `!` in front of apply. Then put it all inside `foo_vec[!apply(sapply(.......))]` and you'll be able to see what happened.

Comment: hahaha, ooh checked that and now I understand. Thanks! I'm gonna get a Yoghurt! haha

Comment: now I'm curios. Is there a way to keep the order of appearance?. Oh I saw how. XD hehe